# Pandas - pivot a column into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns that I want to convert them into rows under a new column called 'variable' while the values are kept in a new column called 'value'. I tryed using transpose and pivot but I wont get the deisred result.

This is my dataframe:

```
|   | date       | speed | meters | pallets |
|---|------------|-------|--------|---------|
| 0 | 2020-03-05 | 300.0 | 1500.0 | 9       |
```

This is my desired dataframe:

```
|   | date       | variable | value  |
|---|------------|----------|--------|
| 0 | 2020-03-05 | speed    | 300.0  |
| 1 | 2020-03-05 | meters   | 1500.0 |
| 2 | 2020-03-05 | pallets  | 9      |
```

Comment: look at melt: `df.melt('date')`

Comment: Yeah that did the job, thanks